# OpenCv window cascading the screen when it's clicked on

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pywin32

I wrote this code to capture screen footage by taking screenshots everything second, however the OpenCv window cascades the screen when it's clicked on.

[image]

When you hover over the Opencv window, it shows me the screen without a hundred duplicates. What is exactly the bug? Picture:

[image]

[image]

The code for using the class I made:

```
from window_capture import Window_Capture
from time import time
import cv2 as cv
import numpy

loop_time = time()

wincap = Window_Capture()

while True:
    screenshot = wincap.screenshare()

    cv.imshow('Screen', screenshot)

    print("FPS {}".format(round(1 / (time() - loop_time))))
    loop_time = time()

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        print("Capture Ended")
        cv.destroyWindow(screenshot)
```

The class for screen capturing:

```
import pyautogui
import numpy
import cv2 as cv
from time import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import time


class Window_Capture:
    w = 0
    h = 0
    hwnd = None

    def __init__(self, window_name=None):
        # checking is windowname exists

        if window_name is None:
            print("No window set to capture: Setting to active Window")
            time.sleep(3)
            self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
            print(win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()))
        else:
            # self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
            self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
            print("Window Found: Setting to preferred Window")

        # define monitor height and width and hwnd
        self.w = GetSystemMetrics(0)
        self.h = GetSystemMetrics(1)

    def screenshare(self):

        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = numpy.frombuffer(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

        img = img[..., :3]
        img = numpy.ascontiguousarray(img)

        return img
```

This bug is preventing me from moving onto the next part my image detection project.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is :

```
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
from mss import mss

#import pyautogui
#width, height= pyautogui.size()
width=900
height=900

mon = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': width, 'height': height}
with mss() as sct:
    # mon = sct.monitors[0]
    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        img = sct.grab(mon)
        print('fps: {0}'.format(1 / (time.time()-last_time)))
        cv2.imshow('test', np.array(img))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Note:
When you hover then you won't be seeing many windows beacuse you see the complete window without the opencv window opended and else you see many of them

Answer (score 0):

you see a cascade because you take a screenshot of the window itself, repeatedly.

it's like standing between two mirrors.